# Error message when I click on site content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have created a template and the template is activated. When I try to create a new site with that template, the site is also created. But the problem occur when I use try to go into `All Site Content`, I am getting a error message

> Error
>   An unexpected error has occurred.
>   Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
>   Correlation ID: e5e2a154-1b41-45a5-af9d-f79b704dc281 
>   Date and Time: 4/29/2015 3:00:50 PM

This happens when I try to open Site Contents and Documents.

Does anyone has a solution or know why I am getting this error message.

Comment: The best way to approach your problem would be to get a free log viewer tool for sharepoint 2013 that can provide the complete log information based on the corellation id. Then find the exact problem. I am clearly suspecting this could be due to some missing files while creating the template such as feature files or some xml list definitions.

Comment: Use the correlation id and search in SharePoint logs. This will provide additional error details.